# How to connect my window network share path via Azure data bricks

Tags: filesystems, azure-databricks, network-drive

I have files in local windows network file share path. I could access the file via Azure ADF using Self hosted IR. But we need to load those files via data bricks.

have tried below code

```
spark.read.csv('file:///networkpath/folder/', header="true", inferSchema="true")
```

Also tried loading the file via UI upload manually it's working fine.

But need know how to automate this file upload to DFS files system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Unfortunately, Azure Databricks doesn't support connect Windows Network Share.

**Note:** It's is highly recommended: **Do not Store any Production Data in Default DBFS Folders**

[image]

There are multiple ways to upload files from a local machine to the Azure Databricks DBFS folder.

**Method1: Using the Azure Databricks portal.**

[image]

**Method2: Using Databricks CLI**

The DBFS command-line interface (CLI) uses the DBFS API to expose an easy to use command-line interface to DBFS. Using this client, you can interact with DBFS using commands similar to those you use on a Unix command line. For example:

```
# List files in DBFS
dbfs ls
# Put local file ./apple.txt to dbfs:/apple.txt
dbfs cp ./apple.txt dbfs:/apple.txt
# Get dbfs:/apple.txt and save to local file ./apple.txt
dbfs cp dbfs:/apple.txt ./apple.txt
# Recursively put local dir ./banana to dbfs:/banana
dbfs cp -r ./banana dbfs:/banana
```

[image]

**Method3: Using third-party tool named DBFS Explorer**

DBFS Explorer was created as a quick way to upload and download files to the Databricks filesystem (DBFS). This will work with both AWS and Azure instances of Databricks. You will need to create a bearer token in the web interface in order to connect.

**Step1:** Download and install DBFS Explorer and install it.

**Step2**: Open DBFS Explorer and Enter: Databricks URL and Personal Access Token

[image]

**Step3:** Select the folder where you want to upload the files from the local machine and just drag and drop in the folder to upload and click upload.

[image]