# How to share file from databricks to a windows file share path using python

Tags: python, azure, azure-databricks

Using below code- but getting error as connection reused
Can someone help please

```
import ftplib
ftp_server = ftplib.FTP(HOSTNAME, USERNAME, PASSWORD)
 
# force UTF-8 encoding
ftp_server.encoding = "utf-8"
 
# Enter File Name with Extension
filename = "file1.csv"
 
# Read file in binary mode
with open(filename, "rb") as file:
    # Command for Uploading the file "STOR filename"
    ftp_server.storbinary(f"STOR {filename}", file)
 
# Get list of files
ftp_server.dir()
 
# Close the Connection
ftp_server.quit()
```

Tried the above solution

Comment: post more details - exact error, what are you're specifying in hostname,e tc.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65924739/how-to-connect-my-window-network-share-path-via-azure-data-bricks), Azure Databricks does not support connecting to Windows Network Share. Therefore, you cannot directly share files from Databricks to Windows. However, you can download the file from Databricks by following the procedure below:

Read the file from the file path using the code below:

```
filepath = '<filePath>'
file = spark.read.csv(filepath, header='true')
```

[image]

Use the display command to show the data of the file:

```
display(file)
```

Click the download symbol to download the file into Windows as shown below:

[image]

The file will be downloaded to the Windows file share. Alternatively, you can copy the file using the Databricks CLI by following the procedure below:

Generate an access token from the Databricks workspace and connect using the command below:

```
databricks configure --token
```

The system will ask for the hostname and token key. Provide these values and press Enter.

Hostname -> **https://.azuredatabricks.net**

Token -> **your-token-key**

Execute the command below to copy the file from Databricks to the Windows file share:

```
dbfs cp dbfs:/FileStore/tables/stocplace.csv <windowsfileshare>
```

You can use the `dir <windowsfileshare>` command to check if the file has been copied. The file will be successfully copied to the Windows file share, as shown below:

[image]